# Negative image filter to Black & White mode

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl, shader, android-camera2

I am using https://github.com/natario1/CameraView this library for capturing a negative image to positive and it is using the openGl shaders. I need a filter in which I can capture a negative image to positive in Black & White mode not in the normal color mode (which is currently available in the library). I tried to mix the two filters i.e first capture the negative image to positive in color mode and then apply the Black & White mode filter but as I am new to openGl, I was unable to do this. Please help me in this regard. It would be highly appreciated. The shaders which I am using are as follows :

```
This shader is used to convert the negative to positive in color mode.

private final static String FRAGMENT_SHADER = "#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require\n"
            + "precision mediump float;\n"
            + "varying vec2 "+DEFAULT_FRAGMENT_TEXTURE_COORDINATE_NAME+";\n"
            + "uniform samplerExternalOES sTexture;\n"
            + "void main() {\n"
            + "  vec4 color = texture2D(sTexture, "+DEFAULT_FRAGMENT_TEXTURE_COORDINATE_NAME+");\n"
            + "  float colorR = (1.0 - color.r) / 1.0;\n"
            + "  float colorG = (1.0 - color.g) / 1.0;\n"
            + "  float colorB = (1.0 - color.b) / 1.0;\n"
            + "  gl_FragColor = vec4(colorR, colorG, colorB, color.a);\n"
            + "}\n";

This shader is used to change the normal positive image in Black & White mode.

private final static String FRAGMENT_SHADER = "#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require\n"
            + "precision mediump float;\n"
            + "varying vec2 "+DEFAULT_FRAGMENT_TEXTURE_COORDINATE_NAME+";\n"
            + "uniform samplerExternalOES sTexture;\n" + "void main() {\n"
            + "  vec4 color = texture2D(sTexture, "+DEFAULT_FRAGMENT_TEXTURE_COORDINATE_NAME+");\n"
            + "  float colorR = (color.r + color.g + color.b) / 3.0;\n"
            + "  float colorG = (color.r + color.g + color.b) / 3.0;\n"
            + "  float colorB = (color.r + color.g + color.b) / 3.0;\n"
            + "  gl_FragColor = vec4(colorR, colorG, colorB, color.a);\n"
            + "}\n";

Please help in making a filter which can direct capture the negative image to positive in Black & White mode.

Thanks.
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do that with a one-liner in a single shader:

```c
gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(dot(1.0 - color.rgb, vec3(1.0/3.0))), color.a);
```

---

Explanation:

the inverse color is:

```c
vec3 inverseColor = 1.0 - color.rgb;
```

For the gray scale there are 2 opportunities. Either straight forward

```c
float gray = (inverseColor.r + inverseColor.g + inverseColor.b) / 3.0;
```

Or by using the [`dot`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/dot.xhtml) product:

```c
float gray = dot(1.0 - inverseColor.rgb, vec3(1.0/3.0));
```

Finally construct a `vec3` from `gray`:

```c
gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(gray), color.a);
```

Comment: Really Thanks. You saved my day. Was stuck in this from last 2 days. Thanks once again.